# sql query to select different select list based on where condition

Tags: sql, .net

I need to select some data using a query where authorized data needs to appear and remaining data should be marked with `XXXXXXXX`, but I need to get all the data from table in a single query.

```
select empid, orgid, fname, lastname, mname, depid, date 
from   employee 
where  orgid in (100,200,300,400,500)
```

output should be like this:

```
10  100 3 "dfdf"  "dfsdfd" "sdfsdfd" "sdfsdfd" "10/10/2010"
20  200 4 "dfdf"  "dfsdfd" "sdfsdfd" "sdfsdfd" "10/10/2010"
30  300 5 "dfdf"  "dfsdfd" "sdfsdfd" "sdfsdfd" "10/10/2010"
40  400 6 "dfdf"  "dfsdfd" "sdfsdfd" "sdfsdfd" "10/10/2010"
50  500 7 "dfdf"  "dfsdfd" "sdfsdfd" "sdfsdfd" "10/10/2010"
XX  XXXX X "xxxx"  "XXXXXX" "XXXXXXX"  "XXXXXX" "XXXXXXXXXX"
XX  XXXX X "xxxx"  "XXXXXX" "XXXXXXX"  "XXXXXX" "XXXXXXXXXX"
XX  XXXX X "xxxx"  "XXXXXX" "XXXXXXX"  "XXXXXX" "XXXXXXXXXX"
XX  XXXX X "xxxx"  "XXXXXX" "XXXXXXX"  "XXXXXX" "XXXXXXXXXX"
XX  XXXX X "xxxx"  "XXXXXX" "XXXXXXX"  "XXXXXX" "XXXXXXXXXX"
XX  XXXX X "xxxx"  "XXXXXX" "XXXXXXX"  "XXXXXX" "XXXXXXXXXX"
```

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: I count 8 columns in your desired output, but your `SELECT` list only has 7 columns.

Comment: Help me understand what you're trying to do here...  So, you want to return the *entire contents of the table*, but censor everything with `X`'s that doesn't meet your `WHERE` requirement?

Comment: Can we assume the WHERE clause is your "authorized" Data?  If you are masking all the other columns with Xs, why even bother returning those records to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

```
select empid, orgid, fname, lastname, mname, depid, date
from   employee 
where  orgid in (100,200,300,400,500)
UNION ALL
select 0, 0, 'XXXX', 'XXXX', 'XXXX', 0, '1900-01-01'
from   employee 
where  orgid NOT in (100,200,300,400,500)
```

The above query should do the job. However, if you are so specific about having 'xx...' in your result set, you need to be casting your resultset to varchar(nn).

Below is an example (of course, you need to replace the fields and table name)

```
SELECT CAST(CourseId AS VARCHAR(20)), Title, CAST(Credits AS VARCHAR(20)),
CAST(DepartmentID AS VARCHAR(20)), CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), GetDate(),101) 
FROM Course
WHERE DepartmentID IN (1, 2)
UNION ALL
SELECT 'xx', 'XXXX', 'xxx', 'xxxx', 'XXXXXX' FROM Course
WHERE DepartmentID NOT IN (1, 2)
```